# Graphql resolveType union: throwing must resolve to an object type at runtime

Tags: javascript, graphql, postman, fastify, resolver

I'm querying a union type in graphql, data comes from MongoDB database, driver: Mercurius, with Fastify framework. I'm trying to implement a search, by fetching data from 2 different database, for example one fetching products the other blog post, so I'm using union to list them both, but the error seems to be persistent.

Below is my schema

```
interface Details {
    _id: String!
}

type Temp {
    min: String
    max: String
    mean: String!
}

type Surface implements Details {
    orderFromSun: Int!
    name: String!
    hasRings: Boolean!
    _id: String!
    surfaceTemperatureC: Temp!
}

type MainAtmos implements Details {
    orderFromSun: Int!
    name: String!
    hasRings: Boolean!
    _id: String!
    mainAtmosphere: [String]
}

type User implements Details {
    _id: String!
    username: String!
    active: Boolean!
    email: String!
    accounts: [String]
}

union SearchResult = Surface | User

type Query {
    add(x: Int, y: Int): Int
    planets: [MainAtmos]
    single_planet(id: String!): Surface
    search(text: String!): [SearchResult!]
    searchUsers(text:String!): [User]
}
```

and here's my resolver:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        add: async (_, { x, y }) => x + y,
        planets: async (_, args, context, info) => {
            const result = await db.find().toArray();
            return result
        },
        single_planet: async (_, args, context, info) => {
            const result = await db.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(args.id) })
            return result
        },
        search: async (_, { text }, context, info) => {
            const result = await db.aggregate([{
                '$search': {
                  'index': 'default',
                  'text': {
                    'query': text,
                    'path': {
                      'wildcard': '*'
                    }
                  }
                }
              }]).toArray();

            const response = await usersDB.aggregate([{
                '$search': {
                  'index': 'customers',
                  'text': {
                    'query': text,
                    'path': {
                      'wildcard': '*'
                    }
                  }
                }
              }]).toArray();
            // return result
            const finalResponse = [...result, ...response];
            return finalResponse
        },
        searchUsers: async (_, { text }, context, info) => {
            const response = await usersDB.aggregate([{
                '$search': {
                  'index': 'customers',
                  'text': {
                    'query': text,
                    'path': {
                      'wildcard': '*'
                    }
                  }
                }
            }]).toArray();
            return response
        }
    },
    SearchResult: {
      __resolveType: (parameter, context, info) => {
        // return username ? 'User' : 'Surface'
        if (parameter.hasRings) {
          return 'Surface';
        }

        if (parameter.username) {
          return 'User';
        }

        return null;
      }
    },
}
```

and the error message

```
"Abstract type \"SearchResult\" must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field \"Query.search\". Either the \"SearchResult\" type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function."
```

Is there anything I might have done wrong? Here's my query:

```
query SearchResult {
  search(text: "Elizabeth Ray ch4") {
    __typename 
    ... on Surface {
        name
        hasRings
    }
    ... on User {
        email
        accounts
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `return null;` would not be allowed I think. Better throw an exception there.

Comment: I don't understand, do I change it to `return {}` or `return`, or completely remove it, I tired all three, same result

Comment: Are you sure, `__resolveType` is actually invoked? Did you try `resolveType` function name without `__` as it says in the error message?

Comment: All I can say is Thank you @NilsHartmann it did work, This has taken me a week and no movement. I'll learn to read the error messages more properly from now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SearchResult: {
  //-- __resolveType
  resolveType: (parameter, context, info) => {
    // return username ? 'User' : 'Surface'
    if (parameter.hasRings) {
      return 'Surface';
    }

    if (parameter.username) {
      return 'User';
    }

    return null;
  }
},
```

Change `__resolveType` to `resolveType`.

Comment: This answer helps, but I don't know why.
Is it too specific so that it is not mentioned in the docs? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/

Comment: There is the switch `internalResolversPrefix`:
https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/blob/master/packages/plugins/other/visitor-plugin-common/src/base-resolvers-visitor.ts#L534